# Denormalizing and searching date ranges in Solr

Tags: solr

I need to return documents from Solr that essentially have "blackout periods".

So, I need to return all documents that don't have a blackout period defined for the date range that is passed in.

I'm currently still working through the "schema design phase", but want to make sure what I'm trying to accomplish is both possible and logical with Solr (once Join is available, this seems like it will be trivial, but until then...)

I'm thinking something like this, using multi-value fields:

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="name">My Item Name</field>
  <field name="unavailableDateRange">1/23/2012-1/27/2012</field>
  <field name="unavailableDateRange">3/14/2012-3/19/2012</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="name">My Item Name</field>
  <field name="unavailableDateRange">2/15/2012-2/20/2012</field>
</doc>
```

Obviously I need to figure out the syntax to make sure the date ranges are entered into the index properly, as well as the proper way to query dates, but for clarity's sake here....

So, when searching for items, I would want to only return items that are available during the requested time.

Example: if the dates 2/13/2012 - 2/16/2012 were passed in, item 1 would be returned but item 2 would not.

My questions:
- Is this something that Solr supports with the date range querying capabilities?
- Are there any performance concerns I should be aware of here?

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr supports dates very nicely. You can use range queries like on any other fields: [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) However field have to be single date, not date range itself.

For your situation I would list in unavailableDateRange field every day that should be in the range (multivalue field). Index shouldn't be that much bigger and it's easy to implement bot for indexing as well as querying.

Example query:

```
./select/?q=NOT unavailableDateRange:[2012-02-13T00:00:00Z TO 2012-02-16T00:00:00Z]
```